# develope a website using visulaforce

Tags: web, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm trying to develop a website using *Visualforce* with *Apex*.
But I'm unable.

Please me with the documents and websites regarding them, I'm unable to find docs regarded *Visualforce*.

Comment: How about the links listed [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/User_Interface)? [edit:] Try [this](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Documentation) too.

Comment: Javatechi, I can't help noticing I've gave you some good links already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881725/visual-force-help-add-edit-and-delete and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688507/examples-for-apex-programming-salesforce-com-platform :D What kind of problems do you have exactly?

Comment: i am struck at some part...i want a stand alone website which has mainly text boxes...but the data from object we have created is not retrieving

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment to the question (doesn't really answer the original question):

Let's say your salesforce environment is on https://na5.salesforce.com, your visualforce page is called "myPage", and you want to display on it data from "myCustomObject__c". Let's also say that there exists at least 1 record in the table of myCustomObjects and it's ID is "0067000000AH3ME" (you can see the ID of the object in the URL when you view it like https://na5.salesforce.com/0067000000AH3ME).

If your visualforce page looks similar to this:

```
<apex:page standardController="myCustomObject__c">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Hi Javatechi">
      <p>You're viewing the {!myCustomObject__c.Name} record.</p>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:detail relatedList="false" />
</apex:page>
```

Then this page should display something meaningful when you visit it via this url:
https://na5.salesforce.com/apex/myPage/?id=0067000000AH3ME

If you'll be able to make this example work for you, all the rest like <apex:inputField> and <apex:commandButton> should start to work too.

Comment: yeah correct thank you...this will be helpful to retrieve for one data..what if i want to retrieve all the records ??

Comment: Check out the visualforce component reference (https://na5.salesforce.com/apexpages/apexcomponents.apexp) for <apex:dataTable> example, you'll have both visualforce page and the controller for it. But I doubt you'll be able to make something like "multiple items edit & save" (and that seems to be your goal). My recent answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122038/how-do-i-integrate-salesforce-with-google-maps can help you too (ignore the whole javascript part, focus on the controller and <apex:pageBlockTable> used).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to get started is checkout:

[An Introduction to Force.com Sites](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites)

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Run screaming from salesforce now, before it is too late. It only gets worse.