# Is it possible to pass argument from visualforce apex tag?

Tags: arguments, salesforce, visualforce

I have a function searchWorkByName that takes "key" as an argument and use SQOL to retrieve the data.

In visualforce side, I have a link that calls searchWorkByName but would like to be able to pass argument such as character 'a'

example, (this throws an error)

```
<apex:commandLink value="search!" action="{!searchWorkByName('aaa')}" />
```

Is it possible to do so if not what is the alternatives?

**apex class**

```
public class SearchWorkTest { 

    public PageReference searchWorkByName(String key) {

            //find record of work names starting from provided key character
            workNames = [select name from work__c where work__c.name like 'key%'];
            return Page.searchResult;   
     }
}
```

**visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="work__c" extenstions="SearchWorkTest">
  <!-- Is it possible to pass argument like 'foo' ? -->
  <apex:commandLink value="search!" action="{!searchWorkByName}" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot pass arguments to actions like that.

1 option is to make this variable a normal form field that user can type text/select from dropdown/whatever - if you'll use same name for a variable in Apex (and make it publicly visible by setters/getters), this will work without problems. Check out my answer at [How do I integrate Salesforce with Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122038/how-do-i-integrate-salesforce-with-google-maps) to get started.

Second option - if this search must be somehow done programatically without user having to click anything, if the data for example comes from page itself (i.e. is read in `<apex:repeat>` tag)... you could make a small helper page & controller and call them as components. There is no problem with passing data to components. Check documentation for `<apex:component>` and `<apex:componentBody>`. But I think first answer os most useful for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

You can pass in parameters from a page into a function like this:

```
<apex:commandLink value="search!" action="{!searchWorkByName}">
  <apex:param name="key" value="val"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Obviously, the value of the parameter in this case is fixed. If you want something dynamic (i.e. user types something and that is passed to the function), I'm not 100% sure how you'd do that, but I think it might be possible. However, the solution already posted skins the cat for you, but I thought I'd follow up with an alternative in case it's any use.