# Google Map Integrated with Salesforce is Blank

Tags: google-maps, salesforce

I followed the example code line by line from:

[How do I integrate Salesforce with Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122038/how-do-i-integrate-salesforce-with-google-maps)

I am not receiving any errors but my Map is blank. The map displays the zoom and position toggle but nothing else.

Any ideas on why?

Here is my Controller Code and Page Code Below

```
 public class mapController2 {
    public String address {get;set;}
    private List<Account> accounts;

    public void find() {
        // Normal, ugly query.
       /* address = 'USA';
        String addr = '%' + address + '%';
        accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingCountry FROM Account 
        //WHERE Name LIKE :addr OR BillingStreet LIKE :addr OR BillingCity LIKE :addr OR BillingCountry LIKE :addr];
        WHERE BillingCountry LIKE :addr];*/

       // address = 'Austin';
        String addr = '*' + address + '*';
        // Or maybe a bit better full-text search query.
        List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :addr IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
            Account (Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry)];
        accounts = (List<Account>)searchList[0];
    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

Page Code

```
<apex:page controller="mapController2" tabStyle="Account">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
#map {
  height:350px;
}
</style>
</head>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search by Address">
        <apex:inputText value="{!address}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!find}"/>
        <p>Examples: "USA", "Singapore", "Uni", "(336) 222-7000". 
           Any text data (free text, not picklists, checkboxes etc.) will do.
        </p>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Matching Accounts" rendered="{!address != null}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="account" id="accountTable">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header"><b>Name</b></apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLink value="../{!account.Id}">{!account.Name}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header"><b>Address</b></apex:facet>
                {!account.BillingStreet}, {!account.BillingCity}, {!account.BillingCountry}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Map" rendered="{!address != null}">
        <div id="log"></div>
        <p>Tip: hover mouse over marker to see the Account name. Click to show the baloon.</p>
        <div id="map">Placeholder - map will be created here.</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
// First we need to extract Account data (name and address) from HTML into JavaScript variables.
var names = new Array();
var addresses = new Array();

var htmlTable = document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:j_id7:accountTable').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < htmlTable.length; ++i) {
    names.push(htmlTable[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]);

    // We need to sanitize addresses a bit (remove newlines and extra spaces).
    var address = htmlTable[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML;
    addresses.push(address.replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,""));
}

var coordinates = new Array();    // Array of latitude/longitude coordinates.
var markers = new Array();        // Red things we pin to the map.
var baloons = new Array();        // Comic-like baloons that can float over markers.
var counter = 0;

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    navigationControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
    }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

if(addresses.length > 0) {
    geocodeOneAddress();
}

function geocodeOneAddress(){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: addresses[counter]}, processGeocodingResults);
}

function processGeocodingResults(results, status) {
    ++counter;
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        coordinates.push(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
        logError(addresses[counter] + " could not be found, reason: " + status);
    }

    if(counter == addresses.length) {
        finalizeDrawingMap();
    } else {
        geocodeOneAddress();
    }
}

function finalizeDrawingMap() {
    // Compute min/max latitude and longitude so we know where is the best place to center map & zoom.
    var minLat = coordinates[0].b;
    var maxLat = coordinates[0].b;
    var minLong = coordinates[0].c;
    var maxLong = coordinates[0].c;

    for(i=0;i < coordinates.length; i++){
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({ position: coordinates[i], map: map, title: names[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML, zIndex:i}));
        baloons.push(new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<b>'+names[i].innerHTML + '</b><br/>' + addresses[i]}));

        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            baloons[this.zIndex].open(map,this);
        });

        minLat = Math.min(minLat, coordinates[i].b);
        maxLat = Math.max(maxLat, coordinates[i].b);
        minLong = Math.min(minLong, coordinates[i].c);
        maxLong = Math.max(maxLong, coordinates[i].c);
    }
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(minLat + (maxLat-minLat) / 2, minLong + (maxLong-minLong) / 2));

    // All that is left is to possibly change the zoom. Let us compute the size of our rectangle.
    // This is just a rough indication calculation of size of rectangle that covers all addresses.
    var size = (maxLat-minLat) * (maxLong-minLong);
    var zoom = 13;

    if(size > 7100) {
        zoom = 2;
    }
    else if(size > 6000) {
        zoom = 3;
    }
    else if(size > 550) {
        zoom = 4;
    }
    else if(size > 20) {
        zoom = 6;
    }
    else if(size > 0.12) {
        zoom = 9;
    }
    map.setZoom(zoom);
}

function logError(msg) {
    var pTag = document.createElement("p");
    pTag.innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById('log').appendChild(pTag);
}
        </script>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi! I've completely rewritten this answer. Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ya even I was getting a blank map but try to do

https://c.na3.visual.force.com/apex/map?id=0015000000UsQZR

Make sure you enter a valid account id to use.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

var address = "{!Account.BillingStreet}, {!Account.BillingPostalCode} {!Account.BillingCity}, {!Account.BillingState}, {!Account.BillingCountry}";

function initialize() {
if(GBrowserIsCompatible())
{
  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("MyMap"));
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());

  geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
  geocoder.getLatLng(
    address,
    function(point) {
      if (!point) {
        document.getElementById("MyMap").innerHTML = address + " not found";
      } else {
        map.setCenter(point, 13);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker.bindInfoWindowHtml("Account Name : <b><i> {!Account.Name} </i></b> 
 Address : "+address);
      }
    }
  );
}
}
</script>


<div id="MyMap" style="width:100%;height:300px"></div>
<script>
    initialize() ;
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Hope this helps

Thanks
tosha
And use the code given as:

Answer (score 0):

> src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"

Use

> https

not

> http

It will definately be blank in firefox or chrome if using http and not https. Try `https`.