# Salesforce:How to insert value for Goelocation datatype field using java?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am inserting object into salesforce using REST API. I have one field with Geolocation data-type.
How can inset value to this field using java? My example code is below.

parishud.put("gps__c",?????);

there are two fields to insert(gps(Latitude) gps(Longitude)) but in API i found only one field with name gps__c

```
  HttpClient client = new httpclient.HttpClient();
  JSONObject parishud = new JSONObject();
  try {
      parishud.put("Name","ParishudhTest4");
      parishud.put("entitled__c","Yes");

      parishud.put("Comments__c","Comments");
      parishud.put("fallill_count_after__c","5");
      parishud.put("fallill_count_before__c","7");
      parishud.put("influencedcount__c","8");
      parishud.put("toiletusaseperday__c","3");
      parishud.put("parishudhid__c","002");
      parishud.put("Received_NBA_Incentive__c","Yes");
      parishud.put("Received_NREGA_Incentive__c","Yes");

      //parishud.put("gps__c",?????);


    PostMethod postaccount = new PostMethod("https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Parishudh__c/");
    postaccount.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
    postaccount.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(parishud.toString(),"application/json", null));
    client.executeMethod(postaccount);
```

Comment: I am able to insert object with out gps__c field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geolocation field is actually composed out of 3 fields, 2 of which are accessible for us.

If your field name is `gps` then you can store your data in `gps__Latitude__s` and `gps__Longitude__s` (note the double underscore in the beginning like it's a managed package and the ending is "s", not "c").

Make sure you have set profile-level security for your Java integration user to be able to access this field.

If you need code samples - you can check my answer [How do I integrate Salesforce with Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3122038/313628) or for example http://blog.internetcreations.com/2012/09/creating-a-geolocation-trigger-in-salesforce-winter-13/