# How to customize map marker of lightning:map in Salesforce?

Tags: google-maps, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I tried to change the icon of mapMarkers but it corresponds to the list description and not to the markers themselves. This line displays a map with red markers :

```
component.set('v.mapMarkers', response.getReturnValue());
```

Whenever I try to change their icon, that's not working anymore :

```
var image = '{!URLFOR($Resource.MapMarkers, \'2.png\')}';
component.set('v.mapMarkers', {
     location: response.getReturnValue(),
     icon: image
});
```

I also tried this : http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_maps_enhancements_custom_icons.htm?edition=&impact=

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Aura component? Or is it Visualforce? Or Lightning Web Component?

For Aura: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/documentation
Search on this page for `icon: 'standard:account'`

You can't load your own icon, you're limited to [icons defined in Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/). The format is `category:icon_name`.

Comment: That was Aura component indeed.
Is that possible without using lightning:map ? 
Like consctructing map with google map directly or with leaflet ?

Comment: I've done a manual Google Map integration back in 2010 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122038/how-do-i-integrate-salesforce-with-google-maps) + you might find some blogs, examples. Not sure if they'll still work, back then you needed Google API key, libraries & functions might have changed... Is that custom icon absolutely necessary and warrants hand-crafting it all from scratch? Maintaining? Maybe obtaining a license from Google, Here.com etc? Might  be not worth the effort.